# How to pass fileObj data with Uploadify to PHP

Tags: jquery, events, date, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify for my file uploading:

```
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'scriptData' : {'creationDate':'test1','modificationDate':'test2'},
    'onSelect' : function(event,ID,fileObj) {
        console.log(fileObj.creationDate.time);
        //alert('The file ' + fileObj.name + ' was added to the queue.');
        }
    });
```

From the above code, my OnSelect event can show the creationDate of the file as I have logged **fileObj.creationDate.time**

But I would like to pass this value to my backend when I start the upload process.
I have the scriptData option, but I am not sure how to pass that creationDate since I do not have the fileObj in this case.

Anyone know what I can do to pass the creationDate to my backend script at the same time that the file gets uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your onSelect handler:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifySettings("scriptData", {'creationDate': fileObj.creationDate.time});
```